# why cloudlet.getSubmissionTime() & cloudlet.getExecStartTime() in cloudsim returns same value?

Tags: cloudsim

i wanted to compute the response time for all cloudlets submitted. for that i am using the following statement:

```
responsetime = cloudlet.getExecStartTime() - cloudlet.getSubmissionTime();
```

The problem i am facing is that the two methods cloudlet.getSubmissionTime() & cloudlet.getExecStartTime() returns same value. Please suggest solution for the same

Comment: Which scheduling policy are you using?

Answer (score 0):

responsetime = cloudlet.getFinishTime()- cloudlet.getExecStartTime()